# Reflection , java , iterate on collection

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I'm writing a function that will iterate on some collection , I don't know what collection I'm getting , so I wrote this till now , the PrintFieldsOfClass will get some object or collection of objects and I will have to print the fields of the class , I have it working for some class , want to add collection support.

```
void PrintFieldsOfClass(Object obj){
    if(obj ==null){
        return;
    }
    Class<?> mainClass = obj.getClass(); // create instance of the class
    Class<?>[] interfaces =null;
    Object collection = null;
    int isCollection = 0; //1 - for List , 2 -  For Set , 3 - Map
    if(mainClass !=null ){
        interfaces = mainClass.getInterfaces();
    }
    try {
        if(interfaces!=null ){
            for(Class<?> interface1 : interfaces ){



                if(interface1.getName().toString().equals("java.util.List"))                     {
                    isCollection = 1;
                    collection = new ArrayList<Object>();
                }
                else            if(interface1.getName().toString().equals("java.util.Set")){
                    isCollection=2;
                    collection = new HashSet<Object>();
                }
            }
        }
```

`

After I know what collection I got , how do I cast the object to that collection ? How do I iterate over it ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to iterate on the collection , already wrote a function that handles any class , now I want to extract any class from the collection and handle it one by one .

Comment: Why not cast it to an `Iterable` and be done with it? Why have a method that takes an `Object` in the first place - can you not make it more specific? Presumably the caller knows that type of `Object` it has, no?

Comment: Why do you need reflection here? Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also, `java.util.Map` is not a collection - what exactly would you be iterating?

Comment: I don't know what class I will get as obj to the function , I need to extract it fields ( already know how to do it if it is a class and not a collection) . I want to add a collection support of it , If I get  List<Whatever> list = new ArrayList<Whatever>(); reflector.PrintFieldsOfClass(ar); . Will print the fields of the Whatever class . Will delete the map , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
void printFieldsOfClass(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Deal with collections...
    if (obj instanceof Collection) {
      for (Object o : ((Collection<Object>) obj)) {
        printFieldsOfClass(o);
      }

      return;
    }

    // Otherwise it is a 'simple' object...
    Class<?> mainClass = obj.getClass(); // create instance of the class
    Class<?>[] interfaces =null;
    Object collection = null;
    int isCollection = 0; //1 - for List , 2 -  For Set , 3 - Map
    if(mainClass !=null ){
        interfaces = mainClass.getInterfaces();
    }
    try {
        if(interfaces!=null ){
            for(Class<?> interface1 : interfaces ){



                if(interface1.getName().toString().equals("java.util.List"))                     {
                    isCollection = 1;
                    collection = new ArrayList<Object>();
                }
                else            if(interface1.getName().toString().equals("java.util.Set")){
                    isCollection=2;
                    collection = new HashSet<Object>();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks ! Seems to work , also added a support for arrays :    if (obj.getClass().isArray()) {
       int length = Array.getLength(obj);
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
           Object arrayElement = Array.get(obj, i);
           PrintFieldsOfClass(arrayElement);
       }
   }